# Determining properties of Solutions of an autonomous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Which of the following functions is a solution of a differential
 equation of the form

$$y'=f(y)$$

where $f$ is continuously differentable for all real $y$

(a) $y=sin(t)$

(b) $y=cos(t)$

(c) $y=t^2$

(d) $y=t^3-t$

(e) $y=cosh(t)$

(f) $y=tanh(t)$

What i tried

It is clear that the ODE must be an autonomous ODE. I picked $(c)$ because since

$$y=t^2$$ is a solution then $$y=t$$ and $$y=1$$ are solutions too.

Hence the solutions are $$y(t)=C_{1}+C_{2}(t)+C_{3}(t^2)$$

Differentiating the above expression gives

$$y'(t)=C_{2}+2_C{3}(t)$$

Which is of the form $$y'=f(y)$$ Im unsure of my answers though. Could anyone please explain. Thanks

Comment: How ever do you reason that if $t^2$ solves an ODE, then so do $t$ and $1$? Furthermore, your equation is of the first order, so the solutions will have only *one* arbitrary constant. Regardless, supposing you pick $y(t) = t^2$, then $y'(t) = 2t$, which is *not* of the form $f(t^2)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's help with your example $y(t)=t^2$. Then $y'(t)=2t$ and expressing $t$ again in terms of $y$ gives $$y'(t)=2\sqrt{|y(t)|}.$$ Of course, this only works without problems for $t\ge0$.

If similar restrictions on the range of $t$ are allowed, then there exist such differential equations for all of the functions.

If no restriction on $t$ is permissible, then you need that the functional relation $y=y(t)$ is bijective and thus invertible, which would disqualify $y(t)=t^2$.

Comment: What about "where $f$ is continuously differentiable for all real $y$"?

Comment: Ah yes, that is even a stronger condition than the bijectivity of $y(t)$. I see only one of the cases satisfying this condition.

Comment: Would it be possible for $y=sin(t)$ or $y=cos(t)$ to be a solution?

Comment: Obviously $y'=\sqrt{1-y^2}$ has $y(t)=\sin(t)$ as solution from minimum to maximum. Which is also obviously not differentiable for all $y$. Similarly for the cosine.